# Graph title is way far from the graph

Tags: graphics

I have added a graph to my `.tex` document but the title appears far away from the graph itself:

[image]

Here is script:

[image]

I am new to LaTeX and do not know how to fix this. Any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: put `\caption{How greedy...}`  _inside_ the `figure` so it moves with the image, also delete those `\bigskip` which will be adding spurious space at the original place, when the figure is inserted elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. plz put this as an answer so i can mark it

Comment: ... and remove `\centering` and `\def\svgwidth{...}` ... and change `scale=0.5` by `width=\linewidth` ...and put `\label{fig:greedy}` inside the `\caption{}` in order to put some like "See figure `\ref{fig:greedy}`" somewhere.

Comment: @Fran thx :) everything works better the way you mentioned, except for  \label{fig:greedy} i think i used it wrong   like this    \caption\label{fig:greedy}{How greedy forward selection algorithm works}

Comment: @asmgx The label must be nested **inside** the caption argument or **after** the caption, e.g.: ` \caption{How greedy ...\label{fig:greedy}}` or ` \caption{How greedy ...} \label{fig:greedy}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
\caption{How greedy...}
```

inside the `figure` so it moves with the image, also delete those `\bigskip` which will be adding spurious space at the original place, when the figure is inserted elsewhere.